# R, how to change size of numbers in colorfulVennPlot?

Tags: r

I need to increase the size of the numbers in a Venn diagram created with colorfulVennPlot as in example below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(colorfulVennPlot)
y <- c(37,29,6,232,121,77,25)
names(y) <- c("001","010","011","100","101","110","111")
labels <- c("A","B","C")
plot.new()
plotVenn3d(y, labels, Colors=rainbow(7), Title = "This is an example of a 3D Venn plot")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels and title can be adjusted with the `shrink` parameter. But I don't see a way to change the numbers inside the Venn diagram in the current version of `plotVenn3d`. There might be an easier workaround, but one option is to create a tweaked version of the `plotVenn3d` function with a new parameter added for adjusting the size of the numbers.

To get the function code, just type `plotVenn3d` in the console. Copy the code to a new R script file and give the function a new name, say, `myVenn`. Now, go to the last line of the function and change it from this:

```
    for (i in 1:7) grid.text(values[i], centerLocations[i, 1], 
    centerLocations[i, 2])
```

to this:

```
    for (i in 1:7) grid.text(values[i], centerLocations[i, 1], 
    centerLocations[i, 2], gp=gpar(fontsize=num.size))
```

Notice how we added a new argument `num.size` that sets the font size for the numbers inside the Venn diagram. Now go back to the top where we declare the function arguments, and change it from this:

```
myVenn = function (x, labels = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                   Colors = c("red", "yellow", "orange", "lightblue", "purple", 
                              "green", "grey"), 
                   Title = NULL, shrink = 1, rot = 0)
```

to this (in order to add the `num.size` argument to the function declaration):

```
myVenn = function (x, labels = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                   Colors = c("red", "yellow", "orange", "lightblue", "purple", 
                              "green", "grey"), 
                   Title = NULL, shrink = 1, rot = 0, num.size=20)
```

Run the code for the new function to load the function into the global environment. Now you can use `myVenn` to plot your data and play with the value of `num.size` until you get something you like.

For example:

```
myVenn(y, labels, Colors=rainbow(7), Title = "This is an example of a 3D Venn plot", 
       num.size=50)
```

[image]